# Selenium error when trying to find xpath for "Not Now" button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to do a Instagram bot and I am at the the beggining.
Selenium doesn't want to click the "Not Now" Button because of this error:

"selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //button[text() = "Not now" because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[text() = "Not now"' is not a valid XPath expression."

Here is the code by now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
numeleUsername = input("username: ")
parolaPassword = input("password: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)



driver.get("https://instagram.com/")
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Accept']").click()
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="username"]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="password"]') 
username.click()
username.send_keys(numeleUsername)
password.click()
password.send_keys(parolaPassword)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type = "submit"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text() = "Not now"').click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[text() = "Not Now"]'))).click()
```

Simply wait and click on the element it's **Not Now** instead of **Not now** btw.

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the closing square bracket.

`//button[text() = "Not now"]`

Comment: I can't believe I put a question on StackOverflow for this

Comment: Dude I checked it like 3 times

Comment: No it's not this

Comment: Add the HTML code to your OP then so we can better see what's going on

Comment: try swapping your quotes.  Double quotes at the ends wrapping it, and 'Not now' in single quotes

Comment: Is it giving you the same error about it not being a valid xpath expression, or is it a new error?